# How many IIS web sites & SSL certificates we need for hosting our 5 Remote event receivers addin inside Azure VM

Tags: azure, ssl, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I want to host 5 provider hosted addins for our sharepoint online sites. now the provider hosted addins implement Remote Event receivers. So we have purchased an Azure VM to host the Remote Event Receivers.

But i have the following questions:-

1. how many IIS web sites we need to have inside the Azure VM? do we need to have 5 IIS sites (one site for each RER)? or we only need one IIS web site which can host 5 ++ RERs??
2. how many SSL certificates we need to have? as i know RER need to be hosted under https.. but i am not sure how many certificates we need?

Thanks

Comment: why down vote and why 1 close request!! i asked this question on MSDN, and i was adviced to post it here, by one of MS moderators. here is the link inside MSDN https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/475c3729-19aa-4bcc-8235-f05909cbe8b4/how-many-iis-web-sites-ssl-certificates-we-need-for-hosting-our-5-remote-event-receivers-addin?forum=Offtopic#475c3729-19aa-4bcc-8235-f05909cbe8b4

Comment: Your question is too vague to answer accurately. Generally, determine how many hosts/servers depend on networking traffic capacity, storage, and computing,.. etc. Rely on requirement analysis and system architecture. I think the sharepoint add-ins just functionally might be placed in the same host. The SSL certificates depend on how many domain names. It is nothing to how many hosts or VMs.

Answer (score 1):

For your second question you should only need one SSL certificate as long as your servers are under the same root domain and your SSL certificate is wild carded e.g The SSL certificate proves *.example.com and not just example.com